# Engineering notation with Haskell

Tags: haskell, floating-point, formatting, floating-point-precision, scientific-notation

Is there a existing Haskell function which provide an **engineering notation** formatting (as String)?

If not, I read that `printf` can be extended by adding an instance to `PrintfArg`. Do you believe this is a good solution ?

---

*By engineering notation, I mean an exponent notation whose exponent is a **multiple of 3**.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I manage to get what I want.
The function to get the engineering format work in a few steps :

**1. Dissociate the exponent from the mantissa**

It's necessary to get the exponent apart of the mantissa.
The function `decodeFloat` (provided by `base`) decode a floating point number and return both the mantissa and the exponent **in power of 2** (mant2 * 2 ^ ex2).

**2. Get the mantissa and exponent expressed in the correct base**

A conversion in **power of 10** is required. This is the role of this function.

```
decompose :: Double -> (Double,Int)
decompose val = if mant2 > 0 
                     then (mant10,ex10)
                     else (-mant10,ex10)
  where
        (mant2,ex2) = decodeFloat val
        res = logBase 10 (fromIntegral (abs mant2)::Double) + logBase 10 (2 ** (fromIntegral ex2::Double)) 
        ex10 = floor res
        mant10 = 10**(res - (fromIntegral ex10::Double))
```

**3. Set the exponent at a multiple of 3**

The function `ingen` test the result of the integer division of the exponent and perform the adjustement on mantissa and exponent.

```
ingen :: Double -> (Double,Int)
ingen val 
  | mod ex 3 == 0 = (mant,ex)
  | mod ex 3 == 1 = (mant*10,ex-1)
  | mod ex 3 == 2 = (mant*100,ex-2)
  where
        (mant,ex) = decompose val
```

Here are some conversions :

```
Prelude> ingen 10e7
(99.99999999999979,6)
Prelude> ingen 10e-41
(100.0,-42)
Prelude> ingen (-72364e81)
(-72.36399999999853,84)
```

---

I performed some tests with quickCheck on a wide range and a large amount of value. The conversion **seems** to work well despite a **very small** difference of value (rounding during the calculations due to the precision?).

However, another verifications should be made.

If you find a mistake or an improvement in these functions, please share.

Answer (score 0):

In [`Data.Text.Format`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-format-0.3.0.7/docs/Data-Text-Format.html) there's an `expt` function that will help format numbers in that way, though it's in a hugely obfuscated library, I'm afraid, and you'll have to convert from `Text` to `String`.

It seems that this is the only one available, but you could always make one yourself.

Comment: This does not seem to conform to the specification, "whose exponent is a multiple of 3". Specifically, `expt 0 10` gives `"1e2"`, and 2 is not a multiple of 3.

Comment: @DanielWagner that's odd; in the library, it says it's in enginerring notation. That might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a standard function. Adding something to `printf` would be one way to go, but it would be a bit annoying to use (since you would need to add a new type for engineering-notation-formatted numbers, and convert numbers to this type before handing them off). Simply writing a standalone function with a type like

```
showEngineer :: Double -> String
```

may be a simpler and more readable solution in the long-term.